# Unable to install Homebrew in Terminal

Tags: terminal, homebrew

[image]I was trying to install Homebrew in Terminal. I have MacOs Catalina 10.15.7. I am the admin of my computer. But i keep getting the following messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is rather clearly informing you that the command you executed is the old ruby based installer. You should go to the Homebrew website and re-copy the bash based installer from the https://brew.sh website.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But now I got another error:

Comment: Using the brew doctor command can be informative.